# get facebook page insights in web app

Tags: facebook, facebook-access-token, facebook-authentication

My company is building a marketing analytics tracking platform. The basis of the integration is I need to get page insights for a company's page(s) so that any of the users in the company can see them not just a particular user so I don't believe that the Facebook login or graph API is going to help.

The pages are our client companies pages, we can get access to the pages using Business manager or something, if needed.

But we need it so that anyone from a particular company can see the page insights for their company's page(s).

Does Facebook have an API that I can use to get page insights that isn't user specific?